# Fix glitchy scroll-based animations in Edge?

Tags: javascript, scroll, microsoft-edge

I'm building a site that has the header change colour as you scroll through different sections on the page, it does this by showing/hiding different layers of different coloured headers, tracking the tops/bottoms of pages to keep them aligned as you scroll. Works fine in Chrome, Firefox etc.

But, Edge, so frustratingly, is glitchy as hell with scroll-based animations. I've had this issue before many times, and not found a solution, and haven't been able to find a whole lot online regarding the issue.

I've created a stripped down test case. It's just header element that's translated on the Y axis the same amount as the scrollTop, so that it stays aligned with the top of the page.

Although my animations animates different layers in a fixed position element, this test case demonstrates the exact same glitchiness.

It's as if the scrollTop values fluctuate, or there's some delay to the styling being applied.

This issue also affects scroll-based parallax too, making it jitter up and down rapidly as scrolling.

The glitchiness still happens when not using a requestAnimationFrame loop, too.

Test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding-bottom: 4000px;
            }

            #header {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100px;
                border: 2px solid #444444;
            }

            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            Test Header
        </header>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var header = document.getElementById('header'),
                scrollTop = 0,
                loopTimeout = null;

            function frame() {
                scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

                header.style.transform = 'translateY(' + scrollTop + 'px)';

                if (loopTimeout) {
                    requestFrame();
                }
            }

            function requestFrame() {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
            }

            function endLoop() {
                clearTimeout(loopTimeout);

                loopTimeout = null;
            }

            function startLoop() {
                loopTimeout = setTimeout(endLoop, 500);
            }

            function onWindowScroll() {
                let frame = loopTimeout;

                endLoop();
                startLoop();

                if ( ! frame) {
                    requestFrame();
                }
            }

            window.addEventListener('scroll', onWindowScroll);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any other workaround other than to take control of the scrolling behaviour. It's really nasty, dirty, and any other negative descriptor that could be thought up - but hey it works. Would love to hear of a better solution, though.

Solution:

```
applyIEFixes() {
    let container,
        scrollTop;

    // IE 11 needs documentElement as container
    if (this.app.IEVersion <= 11) {
        container = document.documentElement;
        scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

    // Edge needs body, however
    else {
        container = document.body;
        scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    }

    let onWheel = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        scrollTop += event.deltaY;

        if (scrollTop < 0) {
            scrollTop = 0;
        }

        if (scrollTop > this.maxScrollTop) {
            scrollTop = this.maxScrollTop;
        }

        // So we can have some sort of smooth scrolling, still
        TweenLite.to(container, 0.2, {
            scrollTop,
            ease: Power2.easeOut
        });
    };

    let onScroll = () => {
        scrollTop = container.scrollTop;
    };

    container.addEventListener('wheel', onWheel, { passive: false, capture: true });
    // 300ms after last scroll, update the current scrollTop value
    window.addEventListener('scroll', Helpers.delayedFunction(300, onScroll), { passive: false });
}
```